# wget GnuTLS: Error in the pull function when trying to install foundryvtt through timed link on raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux, curl, wget, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to set up Foundry VTT on a Raspberry Pi 4 running the latest 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS Lite operating system. Currently I'm remoting into the Pi with Putty.

I've been following the instructions on this site:
[text](https://foundryvtt.wiki/en/setup/linux-installation)
And I'm up to step C.3 with no issues so far.

But when I try to run the command:
`wget --output-document ~/foundry/foundryvtt.zip "<download url>"`
with the temporary url I get from Foundry's website, I get the following output:

```
--2023-09-16 16:55:20--  https://foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/11.308/FoundryVTT-11.308.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA2KJE5YZ3BCQQ6DH3&Signature=69XMWxkkTqJC%2FKhtnByguir489o%3D&Expires=1694898015
Resolving foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com (foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.92.195.129, 52.218.204.138, 52.218.247.227, ...
Connecting to foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com (foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.92.195.129|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: Error in the pull function.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

So far I've tried the following:

- I've made sure to get a new temporary link every time I run the command, just in case it expired.
- I've made sure the Pi has the correct date and time set
- I've updated wget by running `sudo apt-get install wget` with the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.21-1+deb11u1).
wget set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

- I've run the command with --no-check-certificate set
- I've run the command with --secure-protocol=TLSv1_1 set
- I've run `sudo /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates --fresh` to update my certificates, with the following output:

```
Clearing symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs...
done.
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
129 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

- I've tried running the curl command instead of wget with the following syntax:
  `curl -o ~/foundry/foundryvtt.zip "<download url>"`

Which produces the following output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to foundryvtt.s3.amazonaws.com:443
```

I'm not super familiar with Linux/Raspberry Pi, so I think this is as far as I can get just by googling.